# Выбор последовательности в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Скажите как правильно сделать выбор последовательности в выражении:

На примере ссылок:

```
http://my.comand.ru/module/processView/show/7?sort={%22todo_list%22:%22a%22}&pci=10&pdi=1&modal_ev=344  
localhost:8080/forum/topic-206897: dfsd
```

Пример выражения https://regex101.com/r/XKX0AA/1
Регулярное выражение: `([\w-:\/]*\S+[.\/-]\w*([\w\?]*(((={))|)))`

Проблема в том как правильно написать сдесь: ((={))|)) что б в 1 случае обрабатывало первую ссылку **http://* **

Мне нужно получить в ответе Первую ссылку И не затронуть вторую. 
Тоесть из кода видно что нужно найти символ ':' в {} => {key:val} но не найти его во второй ссылке. Тоесть сдесь (localhost:8080/forum/topic-206897:) пропустить его.

```
http://my.comand.ru/module/processView/show/7?sort={%22todo_list%22:%22a%22}&pci=10&pdi=1&modal_ev=344
```

Comment: причем тут jquery?

Comment: Етот код у меня используеться в проекте в juery. Я не верный тег написал. Вижу, спасибо.

Comment: А зачем столько скобок ? `(((={))|)` записывается как `(={)?`. А вот что вам не нравится в вашем выражении и что должно быть получено я из вопроса понять не смог

Comment: Проблема в том как правильно написать сдесь: ((={))|)) что б в 1 случае обрабатывало первую ссылку **http://* ** Из текста видно ЧТО ЭТО КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО. Значит оно там не дописано.

Comment: Ещё раз попробуйте сформулировать задачу так, чтобы всем было понятно. Вам нужно обрабатывать только те ссылки, в которых есть символ `{`?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно отлавливать URL, в которых есть что-то вроде `{...:...}` в query string, то как-то так (на абсолютную корректность не претендую):

```
[a-z]+:\/\/\[\w\.\]+\.\[a-z\]{2,}\S+\?\S+{\S+?:\S+?}\S*
```

[Тест](https://regex101.com/r/1dUYKv/2)